# Upload geotiff from bucket on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

If someone can help me. I'm tring to import a geotiff from a bucket using both colab and the code editor but In both the ways I recevie some errors. I'm follwing the official guide. Using phyton in Colab I always receive SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/myusername/projects/ee-project/assets/dhm_01
 gs://bucketname/dhm_01.tif
```

Otherwise by using the code editor I receive "Line 30: At least one Tileset must be provided." and I can't find information about this argument.

```
var taskid = ee.data.newTaskId(1);
print(taskid[0]);

var assetid = 'projects/ee-project/assets/dhm22';
var asset_url = 'gs://bucketname/dhm_01.tif';

var params = {
  'id': assetid,
  'sources': [{"primaryPath":asset_url,"charset":"UTF-8"}]};

ee.data.startIngestion(taskid[0], params);

print()
```

Comment: Since I can't test this, I'm going to comment rather than answer. If the information I provide solves your problem, please let me know so that I can provide it as an answer. It looks like you are trying to run a cloud SDK command from within colab/python. Try running `earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/myusername/projects/ee-project/assets/dhm_01
 gs://bucketname/dhm_01.tif` at the command line instead. Or, if you prefer to work within colab, try following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/Earth_Engine_asset_from_cloud_geotiff#generations).